# problem after boot device (restart or shutdown) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background, pedometer

I'm working on a health application with a step-counting feature.

I'using `pedometer 1.2.5`
https://pub.dev/packages/pedometer/versions/1.2.5

the app is working just fine while the app is not terminated or removed from memory.

so I need a way to make the application work in the background and autostart when the mobile is restarted or reopened.

Comment: share your codes

Comment: the problem is not in code it's i don't know how to do it open app after boot automatically